# List of lists duplicate removal based on 2 elements

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a list of lists that looks like:

```
[[Joel,Green,597], [Katie,Higgins,623], [Joel,Green,123], ...]
```

I want to remove elements of the list by looking at name and surname (elements that have the same name AND surname should be removed). In the above example the resulting list should contain only:

```
[[Katie,Higgins,623]]
```

I have tried the below code, but it performs duplicate removal only if all three elements of some lists are identical:

```
newlist = []
reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")  # read content
my_list = list(reader) #put content in my_list
for i in my_list:
    if i not in newlist:
        newlist.append(i)
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: That's not a proper list. Please fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You better use a `Counter` here that keeps track of tuples containing the name and surname of the person. We can then perform a two-pass algorithm:

1. first construct the `Counter`;
2. next filter the list.

We can do this like:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
my_list = list(reader)

getter = itemgetter(0,1)

counter = Counter(map(getter, my_list))

new_list = [item for item in my_list if counter[getter(item)] <= 1]
```

So we filter all items out of the list, if the `getter(item)` (a tuple containing the first two items) has occured two times or more.

Comment: Did you mean `<= 1`?

Comment: thank you for the reply. How can i print the full names of the removed items in a separate .txt file?

Comment: By serializing it back using the `csv` library

Answer (score 9):

use [DataFrame.drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=['first','last','val']) \
  .drop_duplicates(['first','last'], keep=False) \
  .values.tolist()
```

from docs:

```
keep : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’

first : Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence.
last : Drop duplicates except for the last occurrence.
False : Drop all duplicates.
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you tag `pandas` here is the pandas' way , by using `drop_duplicates`

```
pd.Series(l).apply(pd.Series).drop_duplicates([0,1],keep=False).values.tolist()
Out[1267]: [['Katie', 'Higgins', 623]]
```

More info :

```
l=[['Joel','Green',597], ['Katie','Higgins',623], ['Joel','Green',123]]
```